# shell скрипты на fedora

Tags: linux, bash, fedora

Есть вопрос: работаю програмистом на линуксе, и каждый день нада запускать перед работой много программ для работы, по типу терминала, ide, проектов, папок и куча всего. Недавно узнал про существование shell файлов, которые при запуске запускают команды в терминал, а так как я лентяй, и мне лень каждый раз запускать много программ для работы пришла идея создать свой shell, в котором будет прописан запуск всех нужных мне программ.
Идея следующая: зайти в папку к проге, которая нужна, найти там его исполняющий файл, и потом ./имя_файла, или как то так.
Вопрос: так вообше можна, или это мои влажные фантазии?
Зарание спасибо за ответ.

Comment: да, так можно. А можно просто в оболочке (в xfce точно так умеет) поставить "сохранять сеанс" и все само магически взлетит.

Comment: работать после выключения будет я так понимаю, да?

Comment: да, работает. иногда подглючивает "проводник", но в целом - стабильно.

Comment: окей, попробую, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

> запуск всех нужных мне программ

Здесь есть три принципиально разных варианта. Соответственно и запускаются они по разному.

1. Прикладная программа, которая запускается в Вашем сеансе после логина. Например, у меня, это почтовый клиент, клиент "Телеграм" и т.д. Принципиально важно, что это **ваш** сеанс. Запускаются либо через *.profile* / *.bashrc* (там прописано, где их можно вставлять), либо в настройках системы (по разному, для разных дистрибутивов) в разделе "Программы, запускаемые при старте".
2. Прикладные программы, которые должны запускать **вне** Вашего сеанса, независимо от того, вошли Вы в систему, или - нет. Например - HTTP сервер. В разных дистрибутивах это делается по разному. В современных дистрибутивах, как правило, с помощью *systemd*.
3. Программы, запускаемые по расписанию. Как правило, это делается с помощью какой-то разновидности *cron*. Всякие бэкапы, проверки диска и т.д. Они тоже делятся на две категории: в вашем сеансе и общесистемные.

Answer (score 0):

Можно cделать просто alias в конф файле .bashrc

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]